# is it possible to update NodeJS via script?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js

is there a way to update the **nodejs** version via a **script**. I am currently trying to run some code on **play.js** which is a **javascript** IDE for iPad but it does **not** have a terminal option, and I am currently running into errors because of the current node version within the app itself.

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very unlikely that you'll be able to change the Node.js runtime of the app yourself.

According to the app landing page https://playdotjs.com, it seems the app comes with Node 12.16.0.

The app developer would have to implement a user-facing feature in order to use another runtime/switch versions/download versions.

Keep in mind that in order to distribute Play.js on the App Store, CodeSandbox has to comply with the various and rather strict policies set forth by Apple.

Your best chance is to reach out to the app developer and ask them to either update the runtime or provide the ability to choose one yourself within the app.

Comment: ah I feared that but it makes sense. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: I see you're a new user, do not forget to upvote/accept answers to your questions if you feel like they add value to the community.